# How to get nested reference data at ones from Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have two collections inside my Firestore database.

First, `users` which looks like this:

[image]

Second, `posts` which looks like this:

[image]

I am storing a `reference` to `user` in `post` documents. When I want to fetch a `post`, I also want to fetch `users` detail. Right now I have to do it something like this:

```js
const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(async function () {
  if (initialized && user) {
    let snap = await firebase.firestore().collection('posts').where("author", "==", firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(user)).get();
    let docs = snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      let doc = docs[i];
      docs[i] = { ...doc, author: (await doc.author.get()).data().email }
    }

    setUserPosts(docs);
  }
}, [user]);
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to fetch the user document for every post and not an efficient solution.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to design your data structure in the same way as a traditional database. Cloud Firestore is a NoSQL, document-oriented database and has no tables or rows. Data are stored as documents and are essentially key-value pairs, including primitive fields like strings or complex objects like lists.

An excellent example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) involves storing messages using subcollections. A subcollection is a collection associated with a specific document. You could restructure your data something like this.

```yaml
users:
    userA:
    name: "Donald Duck"
    email: mr.duck@example.com
        posts:
            post1:
                date: 2021-02-09
            post2:
                date: 2021-02-09
    userB:
    ....
```

```js
var messageRef = db.collection('users').doc('userA')
                .collection('posts').doc('post1');
```

Comment: how can I add new postN document?
Can you show the code? How can I know what number of post is the current?